# MySql (local-Online) replication

Tags: mysql, replication

I am trying to apply MySql replication between a local server (Master) and an online server (Slave) and need your help.

** All names (username – password – server name) are just an example and not the real ones.

I have a Local server (Local-1) and I have configured it as (Master) like this:

```
(my.ini)
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
server-id=2962083
log_bin=mysql-bin
log_error=mysql-bin.err
binlog_do_db=test1
```

then I created a New User (User1) with all privileges.

Now to try replication I have used a second local server (Local-2) as a test server and configured it to be a slave server for replication:

```
(my.ini)
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
master_info_repository=TABLE
relay_log_info_repository=TABLE
```

then used shell to apply:

```
CHANGE MASTER ‘TEST1’ TO MASTER_HOST=’Local-1’, MASTER_USER=’User1’, MASTER_ PASSWORD=’Password1’;
```

And after running slave everything worked properly and I have got my databases synced.

Now I am trying to do the same with the online server, but in case to build a connection with my local server (Server-1) I need a Dynamic DNS because I have no fixed IP.

I have registered on noip.com and got the DUC and given my (Local-1) server a name (testpc.ddns.net).
After that I did the following with my online server:

```
(my.ini)
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
master_info_repository=TABLE
relay_log_info_repository=TABLE
```

then used shell to apply:

```
CHANGE MASTER ‘TEST1’ TO MASTER_HOST=’ testpc.ddns.net, MASTER_USER=’User1’, MASTER_ PASSWORD=’Password1’;
```

But it could not connect giving me:
Slave_IO_State   Connecting to master all the time.

I have tried the following;

- Turned off the firewall on Server-1.
- Opened port 3306 for the incoming and outgoing on Server-1.
- Enabled port forwarding on my router as the following:
  Service Name: MySQL Server
  Protocol: Both
  External Port: 3306
  Internal Port:
  Internal IP Address: 192.168.1.50 (Server-1 IP address)
- Tried (mysql-server.ithopehoms.ddns.net) instead of (ithopehoms.ddns.net) on the online server.
- Tried (IP) instead of (ithopehoms.ddns.net) on the online server.

Answer (score -1):

1.cat network dns

2.ping

ping ip/hostname must ok

3.need check error log